# Context initialization failed when tomcat is running

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I made a simple Maven, Spring MVC, web project in IntelliJ.

When i run tomcat7, there is always error on the console and there is no RequestMapping that i inteded, i think.

Whenever i tried to access http://localhost:8080/helloWorld, it is always no response and only 404 error.

In addition, i run the tomcat with tomcat7-maven-plugin.

here is the code.

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

             xsi:schemaLoacation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.spring.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.demo.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Created by moon on 2016-03-24.
 */

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println("this works very well!!!!!");
        mav.setViewName("helloWorld");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello World");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

here is the error.

> Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception
>   is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 73;
>   cvc-elt.1: 'beans' 요소의 선언을 찾을 수 없습니다.     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

I have wrong type on the xsi:schemaLoacation.

I should type this to xsi:schemaLocation.